# CoffeeScript: Extend super method like in Rickshaw Prototype example

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, prototypejs, rickshaw

I'm playing with the fantastic [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) library which uses [Prototype's class-based OOP system](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Class.js).  This includes the `extend` method which allows a sub-class to extend a method in a parent class like this:

[Parent class](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.js#L20):

```
defaults: function() {
  return {
    tension: 0.8,
    // etc...
  };
}
```

[Sub class](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Stack.js#L7):

```
defaults: function($super) {
  return Rickshaw.extend( $super(), {
    fill: true,
    // etc...
  } );
}
```

I'm trying to find the syntax to do the same in CoffeeScript, so that CoffeeScript handles the Class inheritance rather than Prototype.  Can you help?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @tomahaug's answer I got this working, and I have now realised there is a better way.  While `$super` is a Prototype feature, `extend` is actually defined both in [Prototype](http://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Class.js#L45-L48) and the [Rickshaw](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.js#L23-L29) top-level object, like this:

```
extend: (destination, source) ->
  for property of source
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(property))
      destination[property] = source[property]
  destination
```

So making use of this method, the solution looks like this:

```
defaults: () ->
  Rickshaw.extend super(), 
    fill: true,
    // etc...
```

So the only way this could be improved another step is if it turns out that this is built into CoffeeScript in some way.

Comment: Do you want to translate those two examples into CoffeeScript or are you asking if the CoffeeScript OOP system can do something similar?

Comment: I have translated it to CoffeeScript, and it's mostly working.  It's just this pattern that I was struggling with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the parent method and then decorate the result with more information before it's returned, you can do it like this with pure CoffeeScript:

```
class Parent
  defaults: () ->
    return {
       tension: 0.8
    }

class Sub extends Parent
  defaults: () ->
    r = super
    r.fill = true

    return r

sub = new Sub 

sub.tension # 0.8
sub.fill # true
```

Using a library like [http://underscorejs.org/](http://www.underscorejs.org/) would probably make it a little prettier as you could do:

```
  defaults: () ->
    _.extend super, {
      fill: true
    }
```

Comment: Perfect!  Makes total sense now I see it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: No problem, just glad to help! Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Just saw your edit.  Don't think `return r` is optional in this case.  If you leave it out it will return `r.fill` I think.

Answer (score 0):

The CoffeeScript syntax for those two would be:

Parent class:

```
defaults: () ->
    return {
        tension: 0.8,
        # etc ...
    }
```

Sub class:

```
defaults: ($super) ->
    return Rickshaw.extend $super(), {
        fill: true,
        # etc...
    }
```

Notice that this is just one out of many ways to write the code in CoffeeScript.

Also, remember that there's **implicit return** in CoffeeScript, so one can remove the `return` in both cases, given that the methods does not contain any following code.

Comment: Thanks. I don't believe that's right though.  That still uses `extend` and `$super` which are [Prototype features](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Class.js)

Comment: Ah, so you are asking for the same pattern in CoffeeScript, without the Rickshaw library?

Comment: That it.  Rickshaw [uses Prototype](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Class.js) for Class inheritance, and I'm trying to switch it to CoffeeScript.  Will clarify the question.

Comment: I have posted a new answer, using only CoffeeScript :)